# My microphone doesn't work in iOS 7

Tags: iphone

Since the iOS 7 update, when I receive calls, the person on the other cannot hear me, although I can still hear them.  Also, when I try to give Siri a command, Siri cannot hear me.  Has anyone else had that problem too?

Answer (score 1):

Once the alert is answered it wont pop up again. You have to go to: Settings -> Privacy -> Microphone Then check the state of your app.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in the past (on iOS 6 so not sure whether this could be helpful to you). A cold reset fixed the issue with the microphone.